# Saving a figure doesn't save its title position

Tags: matlab, plot

I manually edit the position of the title of some plot as

```
 plot(X,Y);
 t=title('Data');
 set(t,'Position',get(t,'Position')-[0 1 0.4]);
```

But when I save the figure the position of the title gets back to the default position. I'm using Matlab R2014a.

How can I save the position of the title?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, even in earlier versions of Matlab it seems that the *title* of an axes is reset every time the figure is loaded.

To overcome that, use an [`annotation`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) object instead. (`'textbox'` type).

For example:

```
title_handle = annotation('textbox', [.2 .4 .1 .1], 'String', 'Data','LineStyle','none');
```

You will have to work the position(*) by yourself though, and this position is relative to the `figure` (*not the* `axes`), but it is saved with the figure so it will be where you left it every time you load the figure.

(*) *The position in this example in given in* `normalized` *figure coordinates. Adjust it if you are using another figure coordinate system*